# Integrals in Vector Calculus

Tags: vector-analysis

I have the integral:

> $$ \int_{V} d^{3}\mathbf{r} \; \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}.$$

The integral is defined such that the volume enclosed is such that an open surface at time $t$, $S(t)$, moves at a constant velocity, generating another open surface at time $t + \delta t$, $S(t + \delta t)$. The integral is evaluated over thae two open surfaces the closed curve(s) bounding them. Here's a picture:

[image]

The notation should be clear from the the context.

The textbook argues that since $d^{3}\mathbf{r} = \hat{\mathbf{n}}dS.\mathbf{v}\delta t$, the integral can be written as:

> $$ \delta t \int_{S(t)} d\mathbf{S} \cdot \mathbf{v} \; (\nabla \cdot\mathbf{F}).$$

I don't get the line of reasoning involved. Help?

Comment: @Winther Of course. Edited.

Comment: Consider a small surface element ${\rm d\vec{S}}$. In a small time $\Delta t$ this traces out a paralellogram as the surface moves. The volume of this paralellogram is ${\rm d}V = {\rm d}\vec{S}\cdot \vec{v}\Delta t$.

Comment: @Semiclassical Edited.